# Is it possible to pass a set (several) wildcards in rule all of Snakemake file?

Tags: python, snakemake

So, as I am new at Snakemake I'm not sure whether I am fully getting it, so trying my best the way I understand it. I am trying to run my rule, which actually uses another different rule and based on its output creates a new set of files. However, those two have different wildcards and here comes trouble.

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
include: "rules/rule_with_query.smk"
rule all:
        expand(rules.query_hail.output, id=config['listID'], conf=config['confs'])
```

The `rule all` actually doesn't accept several wildcards. However my rule needs two, as there the previous rule, which uses `confs` and the current one requiring `id`.

Here's my rule:

```
def get_query_fName(wildcards):
    return config["listID"][wildcards.listID]
rule query_hail:
    input:
        rules.prev_rule.output
    params:
        config['id1_or_id2']
    output:
        "file_with_data{id}.tsv"
    script:
        "../scripts/script_for_data.py"
```

So, if I try two wildcards at the same time either (the one I put the second) won't work. I have also tried to put them in square brackets, i.e. as a list, but that doesn't work either.

```
    expand(rules.query_hail.output, [conf=config['conf'], idlocus=config['listID']])
```

What should I do then, how should I call wildcards so my rule will work?

Comment: I don't see `conf` being used as a wildcard anywhere in your `query_hail` rule, is that just in `prev_rule`?

Comment: @KeyboardCat yup it's used in `prev_rule`

Comment: If the workflow still won't run, seeing what `prev_rule` looks like might be relevant then

Comment: How does `prev_rule` interact with `query_hail`?  What's the use of `get_query_fName`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `conf` isn't in the output of `query_hail`, Snakemake doesn't know what to do with it - that `expand` is essentially the equivalent of

```py
"file_with_data{id}.tsv".format(id=some_id_from_id_list, conf=some_conf_from_conf_list)
```

for all ids in listID and all confs in confs. There's nowhere for that `conf` to go.

If just writing `rule all` as

```py
rule all:
    input:
        expand("file_with_data{id}.tsv", id=config['listID'])
```

doesn't work, you may need something more to make sure the wildcards in `prev_rule` can be inferred from `query_hail`.